# Lynksys WRT120N wireless router not connecting to ADSL

Tags: wireless-router

I have a lynksys WRT120N wireless router that was connected to Sterlite ADSL modem. The internet connection was working fine through wireless access. I changed the ADSL router because it developed some power issues and got it replaced with the same model/brand from the service provider. However I am not able to access internet now. Here is the current setting

### Sterlite SAM300 XA

IP Address: 192.168.2.1 (I changed it to this IP because the IP address of my ADSL router was same)

### Lynksys WRT120N wireless router

IP Address: 192.168.1.1

If I connect my laptop to ADSL router directly, the internet works fine. It is only that that if I access it wirelessley through wireless router that I am not able to connect to internet.

The IP address setting has been configured to obtain IP address automatically. I have windows 7 OS home edition.

Could someone please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your two routers are on different sub networks, you need to give them both IPs in the 192.168.1.X range. What you wanted to do is set the Sterlite to 192.168.**1.1** and the Linksys to 192.168.**1.2.**